# Logic flaw in trie search

Tags: c++, tree, trie

I'm currently working on a trie implementation for practice and have run into a mental roadbloack.

The issue is with my searching function. I am attempting to have my trie tree be able to retrieve a list of strings from a supplied prefix after they are loaded into the programs memory.

I also understand I could be using a queue/shouldnt use C functions in C++ ect.. This is just a 'rough draft' so to speak.

This is what I have so far:

```
bool SearchForStrings(vector<string> &output, string data)
{
    Node *iter = GetLastNode("an");
    Node *hold = iter;
    stack<char> str;


    while (hold->visited == false)
    {
        int index = GetNextChild(iter);
        if (index > -1)
        {
            str.push(char('a' + index));
            //current.push(iter);
            iter = iter->next[index];
        }
        //We've hit a leaf so we want to unwind the stack and print the string
        else if (index < 0 && IsLeaf(iter))
        {
            iter->visited = true;
            string temp("");
            stringstream ss;

            while (str.size() > 0)
            {
                temp += str.top();

                str.pop();
            }

            int i = 0;
            for (std::string::reverse_iterator it = temp.rbegin(); it != temp.rend(); it++)
                ss << *it;

            //Store the string we have
            output.push_back(data + ss.str());
            //Move our iterator back to the root node
            iter = hold;
        }
        //We know this isnt a leaf so we dont want to print out the stack
        else
        {
            iter->visited = true;
            iter = hold;
        }


    }
    return (output.size() > 0);

}

int GetNextChild(Node *s)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (s->next[i] != nullptr && s->next[i]->visited == false)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

bool IsLeaf(Node *s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (s->next[i] != nullptr)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
struct Node{
int value;
Node *next[26];
bool visited;

};
```

The code is too long or i'd post it all, GetLastNode() retrieves the node at the end of the data passed in, so if the prefix was 'su' and the string was 'substring' the node would be pointing to the 'u' to use as an artificial root node

Comment: why don't use a recursive implementation? Look at the first character of the key: If the character matches one of the childs of the current node, remove the char from the key and recurse into it and then add the character to all the responses. If the key is empty, recurse into all the childs, joining the responses from the different calls.

Comment: I still struggle when trying to write recursive functions in my code it would be much harder for me to do that then to fix what I have already written.

Comment: Heres a little bit more to add on to my original question:
I add the following words { "the", "a", "there", "answer", "any", "by", "bye", "anytime" } into my trie tree, then I search for any starting with "an" and I get an ouput of {"answer", "anytime"} but it leaves out the "any". It should be a simple fix however Its going over my head

Comment: ok, removed my answer, as I believe it will have the same problem as yours. I'm thinking that your problem is the `IsLeaf()` your structure does not have a way of distinguishing between nodes without an entry (i.e. `a-n-y-` prefix to `anywhere`) and nodes with an entry `a-n-y`

Answer (score 0):

(might be completely wrong... just typed it here, no testing)
something like:

First of all, we need a way of indicating that a node represents an entry.

So let's have:

```
struct Node{
    int value;
    Node *next[26];
    bool entry;
};
```

I've removed your visited flag because I don't have a use for it.

You should modify your insert/update/delete functions to support this flag. If the flag is true it means there's an actual entry up to that node.

Now we can modify the

```
bool isLeaf(Node *s) {
    return s->entry;
}
```

Meaning that we consider a leaf when there's an entry... perhaps the name is wrong now, as the *leaf* might have childs ("y" node with "any" and "anywhere" is a *leaf*, but it has childs)

Now for the search:

First a public function that can be called.

```
bool searchForStrings(std::vector<string> &output, const std::string &key) {
    // start the recursion
    // theTrieRoot is the root node for the whole structure
    return searchForString(theTrieRoot,output,key);
}
```

Then the internal function that will use for recursion.

```
bool searchForStrings(Node *node, std::vector<string> &output, const std::string &key) {
    if(isLeaf(node->next[i])) {
        // leaf node - add an empty string.
        output.push_back(std::string());
    } 

    if(key.empty()) {
        // Key is empty, collect all child nodes.
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            if (node->next[i] != nullptr) {
                std::vector<std::string> partial;
                searchForStrings(node->next[i],partial,key);
                // so we got a list of the childs,
                // add the key of this node to them.                
                for(auto s:partial) {
                    output.push_back(std::string('a'+i)+s)
                }
           }
       } // end for
   } // end if key.empty
   else {
       // key is not empty, try to get the node for the
       // first character of the key.
       int c=key[0]-'a';
       if((c<0 || (c>26)) {
           // first character was not a letter.
           return false;
        }
        if(node->next[c]==nullptr) {
           // no match (no node where we expect it)
           return false;
        }
        // recurse into the node matching the key
        std::vector<std::string> partial;
        searchForStrings(node->next[c],partial,key.substr(1));
        // add the key of this node to the result
        for(auto s:partial) {            
            output.push_back(std::string(key[0])+s)
        }            
    }
    // provide a meaningful return value
    if(output.empty()) {
       return false;
    } else {
       return true;
    }
}
```

And the execution for "an" search is.

- Call searchForStrings(root,[],"an")

  - root is not leaf, key is not empty. Matched next node keyed by "a"
  - Call searchForStrings(node(a),[],"n")

    - node(a) is not leaf, key is not empty. Matched next node keyed by "n"
    - Call searchForStrings(node(n),[],"")

      - node(n) is not leaf, key is empty. Need to recurse on all not null childs:
      - Call searchForStrings(node(s),[],"")

        - node(s) is not leaf, key is empty, Need to recurse on all not null childs:
        - ... eventually we will reach Node(r) which is a leaf node, so it will return an [""], going back it will get added ["r"] -> ["er"] -> ["wer"] -> ["swer"]
      - Call searchForStings(node(y),[],"")

        - node(y) is leaf (add "" to the output), key is empty,
        - recurse, we will get ["time"]
        - we will return ["","time"]
      - At this point we will add the "y" to get ["y","ytime"]
    - And here we will add the "n" to get ["nswer","ny","nytime"]
  - Adding the "a" to get ["answer","any","anytime"]
- we're done

Comment: Where are you getting the variable 'i' from here: searchForStrings(root->next[i],partial,key.substr(1));

Comment: @RuneaterDaWizKid, fixed: it should have been `c`

Comment: @RuneaterDaWizKid, reworked the recursive implementation, with more details and an explanation on how it works.